# 'Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config' on rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting this error when I run `rake db:migrate` in a Rails 3.2.12 app running Ruby 1.9.3p194 on Mac OS X 10.8.3.

Here is the output:

```
/Users/redgem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails32/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(in /Users/redgem/viper)
WARNING: rake-compiler found compiled files in 'ext/mysql2' directory. Please remove them.
rake-compiler must be configured first to enable cross-compilation
rake-compiler must be configured first to enable cross-compilation
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I have looked at other SO issues but none are with rake. Thanks!

Comment: @PedroNascimento thanks, but it is using the current version 10.1.0

Comment: Your log shows rake 0.8.7, you might try removing it.